# Readonly selectable EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that need to be switched between normal mode and readonly selectable mode (more specifically it's a kind of highlight mode where selection is set by `setSelection` and user can't change the selection). The problem is that sometimes the selection is not showing up. And after I toggle EditText to readonly selectable mode then toggle it back, when I press somewhere the cursor moved but the soft keyboard isn't showing up.

Here's the code to toggle it to readonly selectable mode:

```
inputText.setFocusable(false);
inputText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
inputText.setCursorVisible(true);
inputText.selectAll();              // for test purpose
```

Here's the code to toggle it back to normal mode:

```
inputText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
inputText.setFocusable(true);           // this line can be omitted according to the source code
```

It seems selecting texts works for the first time and after that it never works unless the application is restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I decided to use another `TextView` containing exactly the same text and display that one (and hiding `EditText`) when I need to "disable" my `EditText`.